# using grouped array in list component - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I get an array grouped by date using an API, like this:

```
const data =  [
  [
    {
      BookSubject: 'book1',
      createdAt: '2020-06-20T19:02:18.308',
    },
    {
      BookSubject: 'book2',
      createdAt: '2020-06-20T19:02:18.308',
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      BookSubject: 'book3',
      createdAt: '2020-06-10T19:02:18.308',
    },
    {
      BookSubject: 'book4',
      createdAt: '2020-06-10T19:02:18.308',
    },
    {
      BookSubject: 'book5',
      createdAt: '2020-06-10T19:02:18.308',
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      BookSubject: 'book6',
      createdAt: '2020-05-10T19:02:18.308',
    },
  ],
]
```

This grouped array is an (array of array).

I want to display each array in a separate list (using list component in ant design).

What I did:

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import { getBooksList } from '../../services/AuthService';
    import { Book } from '../../interfaces/Book';
    import { List } from 'antd';

    const App = () => {
    const [books, setBooks] = useState<Book[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
     getBooksList()
      .then((res) => {
        setBooks(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
      });
     }, []);

     return (
    <>
      {books.map((data: Book[]) => {
        return (
          <List
            dataSource={data[0]}
            renderItem={(item:Book) => (
              <List.Item>
                <h1>hiii {item.bookSubject}</h1>
              </List.Item>
            )}
          />)
      })}
    </>
     );
     };
      export default App;
```

In the list `datasource`, I reach the first array by using `data[0]`.

What I should do if I want to loop through this array (data[0], data[1] .. etc) and create a number of "list" components that equal the array length? (I am using typescript with React).

Comment: You are doing the right thing, only need to change `dataSource={data[0]}` to `dataSource={data}` because `dataSource` accept a list

Comment: this solved my issue. I just misunderstood how list component work

Answer (score 0):

Since the data that  you get in the `API` response is a grouped array.
In order to achieve your desired outcome, you need to `flatten` the array.

You can a achieve this by `flattening` the array before using the `setBooks` method in the following way:

```
useEffect(() => {
     getBooksList()
      .then((res) => {
 
        // flatten the response array and store its output in `flattenedData`
        var flattenedData = [].concat.apply([], res.data);         
 
        // Set the books array with the flattenedData
        setBooks( flattenedData );
      })
  .catch((error) => {
     // log error here
  });
}, []);
```

This will essentially allow you to map through the books array in your component easily.